# Is there a more elegant way to merge observables when return type is unimportant?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveUI-like view model. It has several properties of different types which fire `NotifyPropertyChanged` events and I want to subscribe a method that will be called when any is fired, but I am not interested in actual values.

My current code is a bit ugly (due to opaque `true` selects). Is there a way to express this which shows the intention of just caring when the event occurs?

```
    this.ObservableForProperty(m => m.PropertyOne)
        .Select(_ => true)
        .Merge(this.ObservableForProperty(m => m.PropertyTwo).Select(_ => true))
   .Subscribe(...)
```

I am merging about 8 properties, so it's more ugly than shown.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since this looks like ReactiveUI, how about using the WhenAny operator:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.PropertyOne, x => x.PropertyTwo, (p1, p2) => Unit.Default)
    .Subscribe(x => /* ... */);
```

In general though, if you were combining arbitrary Observables, you could also write this a bit more clearly using the non-extension method:

```
Observable.Merge(
    this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.PropertyOne).Select(_ => Unit.Default),
    this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.PropertyTwo).Select(_ => Unit.Default),
    this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.PropertyThree).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
).Subscribe(x => /* ... */);
```

Also, if you're subscribing to every property of a ReactiveObject, it's probably better to just use:

```
this.Changed.Subscribe(x => /* ... */);
```

Comment: not really reactiveui, observableforproperty is just my extension method which estracts name and returns observable from PropertyChanged eventpattern. Also not subscribing to every property, just some of them.

Comment: WhenAny looks cool though, however as I understand from syntax it still doesn't ignore actual values.

Comment: WhenAny works like Zip, you specify a selector function as the last parameter - in this case, we're selecting to Unit

Answer (score 2):

You could make it an extension method to make the intent clearer:

```
public static IObservable<bool> IgnoreValue<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return source.Select(_ => true);
}

...

this.ObservableForProperty(m => m.PropertyOne).IgnoreValue()
.Merge(this.ObservableForProperty(m => m.PropertyTwo).IgnoreValue())
.Subscribe(..);
```

Comment: yeah could do that. If there is no better alternative would probably do it this way, or make ObservableForPropertyIgnoreValue instead. However in this case we are creating a <bool> value observable which isn't communicating our intent not to use it very well, which isn't very beautiful I think. However we got to observe something I guess so there must be no better way?

Comment: the the [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit(v=vs.103).aspx) type, which will communicate that the return value has no value other than that it exists

Comment: +1 to Scott's suggestion, instead of 'true', use 'Unit.Default'

Comment: agree with Unit.Default I guess its suggested type to use in such case.

Comment: Sorry Scott , you didn't provide an answer so ill mark Pauls with Unit.Default as one.