# How do I merge several observables using WhenAny(...) in ReactiveUI?

Tags: system.reactive, observable, reactiveui

I have a question which is an extension of the following question raised on this site.

[Is there a more elegant way to merge observables when return type is unimportant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010372/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-merge-observables-when-return-type-is-unimportant/21762027#21762027)

I have an `IObservable<Unit>` (lets say `X`), a reactive collection (`Y`) and a property (`Z`). Return type is not important. I just want to subscribe when any of these change.

I know how to observe all 3 and `Subscribe` using `Observable.Merge` as below.

```
Observable.Merge(X, Y.Changed, ObservableForProperty(Z).Select(_ => Unit.Default)).Subscribe(..)
```

And it works.

However, when I try to use `WhenAny(...,....,....).Subscribe()`, the subscribe does not get triggered when my `X` changes. What is the syntax for doing the above using `WhenAny(...)` rather than `Observable.Merge(..)`??

I prefer to use `WhenAny(....)` because I am using `ReactiveUI` in other places.

Example:
Say I've got a class derived from `ReactiveObject` with following properties.

```
public class AnotherVM : ReactiveObject
{
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return this.isTrue; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.isTrue, ref this.isTrue, value); }
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
    }

    public ReactiveCollection MyCol
    {
       get { return Mycol; }
    }    
}

public class MyVM : ReactiveObject
{
    MyVM
    {
       // do WhenAny or Observable.Merge here....
    }
}
```

I want to observe the above properties in `AnotherVM` class using `Observable.Merge(..)` or `WhenAny(...)` in `MyVM` class. I found that I do not always get a notification when I subscribe to the above in `MyVM` using `WhenAny(...)` or `Merge(...)` when either of the 3 properties change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WhenAny` is not for monitoring across sets of arbitrary observables, it's for monitoring the properties of an object supported by ReactiveUI (like a ReactiveObject or reactive collection).

For the general case of combining changes in observable streams, `Observable.Merge` is the right way to go.

EDIT

I note that you have declared the Data and MyCol properties read only. If you use a `Merge` like this:

```
Observerable.Merge(this.WhenAnyValue(o=>o.IsTrue, v=>Unit.Default),
                   this.Data,
                   this.MyCol.CollectionChanged.Select(v=>Unit.Default))
```

...then you must be careful not to change the backing fields. If you do, then you will get missing events - maybe this is what is happening?

In that case you would need to wire up those properties to `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` and use a `Switch` to keep track - e.g. if `this.data` could change then you would need (I'm using ReactiveUI 5 + .NET 4.5 here in case the RaiseAndSetIfChanged syntax looks odd):

```
public IObservable<Unit> Data
{
    get { return this.data; }
    private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref data, value); }
}
```

and your merge would be something like:

```
Observerable.Merge(this.WhenAnyValue(o=>o.IsTrue, v=>Unit.Default),
                   this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.Data),
                   this.MyCol.CollectionChanged.Select(v=>Unit.Default))
```

WhenAnyObservable is conceptually equivalent to this:

```
WhenAny(x => x.Data, vm => vm.Value).Switch()
```

using Switch to flip over to the latest value of `Data` when it changes. Don't forget to use the setter to change values of data!

Comment: That is a good explanation of WhenAny() and clarifies the use case. However, reason I asked is because I 've two properties of a ReactiveObject (Obj) X (IObservable) and Y (a bool), when I use Observable.Merge(obj.X,...), only first change to the property X is raised. Any subsequent changes are not raised. WhenAny(Obj.X, ...) also seems to be doing the same thing. However, when I do object.X.Subscribe(...) my subscribe gets invoked everytime X changes. Clearly, I am not doing something right when using Merge or WhenAny and that is probably because I am relatively new to ReactiveUI and rx!

Comment: Do you consider a new event on the observable stored in `obj.X` to be a change to `obj.X`? It's not - at least not in the sense that `WhenAny` or that particular overload of `Merge` would consider. `WhenAny` would track a new observable stream being assigned to `obj.X`. Subscribing to a stream *is* the correct way to listen to it. Perhaps if you added some code demonstrating your scenario more specifically, then an idiomatic answer may be easier to come by.

Comment: `ReactiveUI` is all about representing property changes and commands as Observables so that you can harness Rx - it's not really there to help you with *existing observables* so much. That's what regular Rx is for.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for all your help. It is helpfuil and I agree an example would be useful. I 've given a small example above in my original post.

Comment: James, thanks for that. Yes ReactiveCollection is read.write..I just excluded it in the example.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
IObservable<Unit> merged =
    Observerable.Merge
    ( this.WhenAnyValue(o=>o.IsTrue, v=>Unit.Default)
    , this.Data
    , this.MyCol.CollectionChanged.Select(v=>Unit.Default)
    )
```

Theoretically you could write a special version of merge that would disregard the type of the observable and return `IObservable<Unit>`. Then you could write

```
IObservable<Unit> merged =
    Observerable.MergeToUnit
    ( this.WhenAnyValue(o=>o.IsTrue)
    , this.Data
    , this.MyCol.CollectionChanged
    )
```

but then you would need many overloads of MergeToUnit for up to the N parameters you would like to support.

The most general pattern to use with WhenAny with multiple objects is

```
Observable.CombineLatest
  ( source0.WhenAnyValue(s=>s.FieldA)
  , source1.WhenAnyValue(s=>s.FieldB)
  , source2.WhenAnyValue(s=>s.FieldC)
  , source3.WhenAnyValue(s=>s.FieldD)
  , (a,b,c,d) => Process(a,b,c,d)
  )
```

It's sometimes just better to get used to using the standard combinators.

Comment: Folded some of this back in to my answer with some extra info, thanks brad. +1